# how to add marker to offline map in Android

Tags: android, google-maps, marker

I get a sample code from the internet that has offline city map. 
I need to add marker to some points . 
How can I add marker to the curent position or some other points in the map?

Answer (score 0):

I would advice you to look at the api:
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/
However I don't think Google maps is supported offline yet. It has only been announced not long ago.

Comment: My sample code is't use fragment. How can I use fragment?